# Landscape light blinks

Tags: electrical

Hoping someone can help.

I have a LOT of landscape lighting and only ONE blinks in the middle of the strand.  I tried adding another light at the end and it too blinks.  Can this be a simple case of the bulb I am using may be too strong?  The wire run is VERY long and I cannot tell you what gauge wire I am using because it was done by a number of people.  I can tell you the power supply/transformer is 300, and all the lights are fine except for those two.

Finally, will going up to a 400 W transformer solve the blinking problem?

Comment: `power supply/transformer is 300` ... 300 what? ... please correct your post

Comment: What is the system voltage? Can you measure the voltage at the farthest socket?

Comment: Try swapping a bulb that doesn't blink  with one that does and see if the problem follows the bulb or stays with the fixture.